# Error appearing while creating a table in my class in oracle 21c

Tags: sqlplus, oracle21c

ora-01031: insufficient privileges in oracle 21c
This Error is appearing when i am creating a new table in SQL . what should i do to give privileges to my user .

I Tried .

1. grant create any view to C##python;
2. grant create session to C##python;

I tried to give privileges with the help of these commands but still doesn't work.

Comment: I guess you need to run `grant create table to C##python;`. Although it's also suspicious that you're using a rarer common users instead of a typical local user that connect to a PDB. Connecting in an unusual way maybe saved you a few minutes of setup, but may cause weird issues later. (But I don't blame you - Oracle's multitenant is overly complicated.)